# Does Braintree payment_method_nonce expire?

Tags: braintree, braintree-rails

I'm building a marketplace app where the user requests for a product, if the sub merchant accepts, then I want to process the transection using the payment_method_nonce, so I was wondering will the payment_method_nonce expire? so that the sub merchant is not forced to accept the offer sooner.

I also thought to hold payment in escrow, but then I'll have to implement a cron job to cancel the transection if the sub-merchant didn't accept an offer (click on email ever).

Any ideas and thoughts please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I feel dumb for asking this, My solution was to create customer > add payment methods (save in vault) > then use that payment_method_token for future payments.

However Braintree experts, please let me know if you'd do it in any other way

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to [contact support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sup>

[Payment method nonces](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/overview#payment-method-nonce) do expire, so vaulting the transaction and processing it later is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: In my case it doesnt work, because creating transactions requires an amount. If i want to gain the token first and capture any amount in the future, is it possible?

Comment: Please reach out to Braintree's support team for assistance: https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/help